# CSS3 transition on page loaded

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I have this CSS code:

```
    <!-- language: css -->    
    div.slider {
        transition: 2.5s cubic-bezier(.25,.77,.74,.24);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 1% 0, 1% 100%, 0% 100%);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 0%;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: auto;
        margin: auto;
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;  
    }

    div.slider:hover {
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    }
```

and this HTML code:

```
    <!-- language: html -->
    <div class="slider" id="slider">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5CAq.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    </div>
```

And I want the animation to start not on `:hover`, but instead as soon as the page loads. 
I was able to find some JS scripts that are supposed to achieve that, but unfortunately none of them seem to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the class from the HTML `class="slider"`.

Add this JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('slider').classList.add('slider');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a css animation with clip-path. see: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/KzLbGe for an example (note, I've read that the number of start and end points must be the same in the animation for it to be valid)

so, you start with css like your initial state:

```
.slider {
    transition: 2.5s cubic-bezier(.25,.77,.74,.24);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 1% 0, 1% 100%, 0% 100%);
    animation: clippath;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

then add your animation states like:

```
@keyframes clippath {
  25% {
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
}
```